# Bootstrap - open modal after postback only after button click c#

Tags: c#, bootstrap-modal

I have just implemented a modal popup on my site to capture email addresses.  Once the user clicks the submit button the form is submitted.  I am calling the modal again after a page.ispostback which works fine.  However, I only want it to display after a user clicks that particular submit button.  As this is on a master page, if someone goes to my 'Contact Us' page and submits a question on postback the modal reappears which I don't want.  I literally only want it to appear after a postback from the submit form on the modal.

Any ideas how I can get around this?

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 0):

To display the `modal` only after the user clicks the submit button, you should put the `modal`'s display logic only in this button's submit event.

Take the logic out of the `Page_Load`'s `IsPostBack`, and put it at the end of this `button`'s `OnClick` event

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do some work...

    // Show modal
}
```